# How can a beginner trader make use of 'volatility of volatility'

Tags: option-pricing, volatility

For a beginner option trader in equity options, how can he use this metric that is provided by his broker/data vendor?
How can he use this metric to gain an added understanding of the option pricing/mispricing?